# Spring Rest Controller not working on weblogic 10.3 / Spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, weblogic12c, weblogic-10.x, spring-restcontroller

I deployed a spring boot rest application to weblogic 10.3 , but the rest resources are not reachable ... It always gives 404 though it was working fine on tomcat and on weblogic 12 ... I tried putting index.html page under webapp , it was reachable (i.e. application is running) but the REST resources are not

weblogic .xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wls:weblogic-web-app xmlns:wls="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.3/weblogic-web-app.xsd">
    <wls:weblogic-version>10.3.6</wls:weblogic-version>
    <wls:context-root>onlinechannel</wls:context-root>
    <wls:container-descriptor>
        <wls:prefer-application-packages>           
            <wls:package-name>org.springframework.*</wls:package-name>
            <wls:package-name>org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap.*</wls:package-name>
            <wls:package-name>org.slf4j.*</wls:package-name>
            <wls:package-name>com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.*</wls:package-name>
            <wls:package-name>com.fasterxml.jackson.*</wls:package-name>
            <wls:package-name>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.*</wls:package-name>
        </wls:prefer-application-packages>
    </wls:container-descriptor>
</wls:weblogic-web-app>
```

web.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
    "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
    "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">

<web-app>

    <display-name>app</display-name>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>15</session-timeout>
    </session-config>

    <!-- The Usual Welcome File List -->
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

dispatcher-servlet.xml : (also not working without it)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
</beans>
```

Comment: Weblogic 10 is a servlet 2.5 container NOT a servlet 3.0 container. To deploy a Spring Boot application to a legacy container you will have to take into consideration the Spring Boot legacy project else it simply won't work.

Comment: you mean spring legacy project not spring boot legacy , right ? because I as I understand spring boot is always targeting servlet 3 ,,,, so can you please provide a resource to start with

Comment: I clearly stated [Spring Boot Legacy](https://github.com/dsyer/spring-boot-legacy)... Spring Boot works on Servlet 3 containers. Weblogic 10 ins't a Servlet 3 container. However if you are using Spring Boot 2 the minimum version is a Servlet 3.1 container and then you simply cannot deploy to weblogic 10.

Comment: can you please clarify more how shall I 'take it into consideration' ... what I understand is that I need to modify the web.xml as in the legacy project and to include the legacy project as a dependency in my project ... please correct me if wrong ... my concern is that the legacy project supports boot 1.1.4 but I am using boot 2.0 ... also am I obliged to include it as a dependency or it's only if I need to use features mentioned such as filters ,security filters , servlets defined by annotations and so

Comment: Spring Boot Legacy doesn't work for Spring Boot 2. As for Spring Boot 2 the minimal required servlet version is 3.1. Hence there is no way you will be able to deploy a Spring Boot 2 application to a weblogic 10 instance as that is as Servlet 2.5 container.

Comment: mmmm ... thanks a lot, but given that I downgrade the version to 1.1.4 , the steps are as I mentioned in the comments, right?

Comment: You downgraded what to 1.1.4?

Comment: spring boot 2.0.0

Comment: I mean use old spring boot dependency and abandon features in spring boot 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Weblogic 10` is a `servlet 2.5` container **NOT** a `servlet 3.0` container.

To deploy a Spring Boot application to a legacy container you will have to take into consideration the Spring Boot legacy project else it simply won't work.

[spring-boot-legacy](https://github.com/dsyer/spring-boot-legacy)